# Angular 4: How can I select an option in <mat-select> in a component unit test?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am testing a component that includes a `<mat-select>` from angular-material.

I would like to change the selected value during the test and then assert that the data in my table is reloaded.

This is what I've been trying, but it does not seem to produce a proper change event:

```
const selectSubregions = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#subregionSelect'));
const selectComponent: MatSelect = selectSubregions.componentInstance;
selectComponent.writeValue(2);
selectSubregions.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Update:
Another variant I tried to trigger the change event:

```
selectSubregions.query(By.css('.mat-select-trigger')).nativeElement.click();
```

Comment: This is functional/integration test that affects several units, including third-party unit. Usually you shouldn't do that in *unit* test. I'd suggest to use dummy component for mat-select selector. The way it should be tested depends on how this form works.